# MVC4 Open Authentication with MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

I have to make an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using MySQL database and OAuth2

But I am unable to make the open Authentication run. Can any one please help? 
Getting the following error
**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**

add name="MySQLMembershipProvider"              type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,

Comment: Hello - could you share some examples of your code? And some more details of what exactly is going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Though you did not specify your problem exactly but hope that will help
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Comment: I want to do it with MySQL not with MSSQL

Comment: Surely the concepts apply across the board!?